# Create new layer by looping throgh unique attribute values

Tags: python, loops, arcgis, arcpy

I´m trying to make a loop through the unique values of a field of a shapefile. the field is named AGLOMERADOS and I want to loop throgh them.
Once i have this list i want to start selecting by attributes my shape file and create one shapefile for each of this selections. 
I get empty shapefiles!!! :(
The code im using looks something like this:

```
import os, arcpy, numpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


def unique_values(table, field):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field]) as cursor:
        return sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})



agloms=unique_values(r'C:\Users\gdorna\Dropbox\CIPUV\lilp\Proyecto LILP 2014 - Infraestructura\Lincoln Infra - GIS\Iterate agloms\agloms.gdb\pais','AGLOMERADO')


i=0
for lugares in agloms:
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("pais","NEW_SELECTION",""""AGLOMERADO" = 'lugares'""")
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('pais', "a_" + `i`)
    print `lugares` + "----->" +   `i`
    i=i+1
```

the list that i should get to should look like this,
agloms= 'BAHIA BLANCA', 'CIPOLLETTI', 'CONCORDIA', 'FORMOSA',...

Yet, my agloms is = [u'BAHIA BLANCA', u'CIPOLLETTI', u'CONCORDIA', u'FORMOSA', u'GRAN CORDOBA'....] why is that?!?!??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The 'u' indicates that the format of the string is unicode.  When you print a list, it's going to include that tag to indicate the string format.  If you were to run the following code:

```
for lugar in agloms:
    print lugar
```

the output would be

```
BAHIA BLANCA
CIPOLLETTI
CONCORDIA
FORMOSA
GRAN CORDOBA
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies with your SQL statement. You are trying to input **lugares** as a variable, but instead it is part of your string.

Instead of this:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("pais","NEW_SELECTION",""""AGLOMERADO" = 'lugares'""")
```

try this:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("pais","NEW_SELECTION", "\"AGLOMERADO\" = '" + lugares + "'")
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```html
import os, arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


def unique_values(table, field):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field]) as cursor:
        return sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})



agloms = unique_values(table, field)


i=21
for lugares in agloms:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(table, "a_" + 'i+1',  "\"field\" = '" + lugares + "'")
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("a_" + 'i+1', r'your out_path', "a_" + lugares)
    print lugares + "----->" +   'i'
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Please add some explanations as well.